Alternatives to SendKeys in PowerShell for a script that manipulates MSWord
The issue I'm dealing with is the unreliability of the SendKeys function. Right now, I'm working on creating a script that opens a Word document, selects "Finish and Merge" -> "Edit Individual Documents..." and then saves the output into a certain folder under a name matching the date.
So far, the script works around half of the time. There have been issues where windows don't open correctly and it doesn't get named right, or it skips over a key or two, leading to undesired results. I have tried the Word module but have had no success. I need this to work, essentially, 100% of the time because it'll be automating the task.
Are there any recommendations on how to lessen the fail rate other than boosting the time between SendKeys calls? I'm open to using any modules to complete this task.
Script (for reference):
$date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
Start-Process -Filepath 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE' '\\kfs\users\L93563\mailMergePap.docx'
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate('Word')
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{LEFT}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("MRE")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("cql.lacny.com SMB NegPap.odc {ENTER}{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("M")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("F")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("E")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("F")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("A")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{RIGHT}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{DOWN 4}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB 10} \\KFS\Confidential\SMB Neg Pap Letters {ENTER}{TAB 6}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$date")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{F4}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{F4}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{RIGHT}{ENTER}")

I've tried both modules listed above, separating keystrokes in the calls, increasing and decreasing the time between calls.

After attempting to implement Menelaos' suggestion, I ran into some of the errors I had faced when I tried using that module initially. I've been looking into them with no luck, I'll update if I find a solution to this issue.
Requested object is not available.
At C:\REAL SCRIPTING HOURS\ws2.ps1:15 char:1
+ $document.MailMerge.Destination = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
This method or property is not available because the document is not a mail merge main document.
At C:\REAL SCRIPTING HOURS\ws2.ps1:16 char:1
+ $document.MailMerge.Execute()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 


Please see my comment on Menelaos' Answer.

Introduction
The problem is that you are not giving large enough wait times.
Instead of wait times, for some of these you could actually actively check if the previous action has succeeded.
However, as a test, try increasing all your delays by a factor of X10 and this should increase your success.
Another problem, can be one of lost focus. You need to also add commands to bring the focus back to the specific window.
Finally, sendKeys can be unreliable. I thnk you should maybe switch to something else, such as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word module in PowerShell to directly interact with Word's object model.
See for example here: Create Word File Using Microsoft.office.Interop.Word
Based on the above, and also the documentation at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interop/how-to-access-office-interop-objects -
I came up with the following example:
Example (using Interop.Word)
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word


$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true


$documentPath = '\\server\share1\menelaos-test.docx'
$document = $word.Documents.Open($documentPath)

# Wait for the document to load
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

# Execute Mail Merge
$document.MailMerge.Destination = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMailMergeDestination]::wdSendToNewDocument
$document.MailMerge.Execute()


$outputPath = '\\server\share1\menelaos-test-out.docx'
$mergedDocument = $word.Documents.Item(2)
$mergedDocument.SaveAs($outputPath)

$outputPath = '\\server\share1\menelaos-test-out-noMerge.docx'
$document.SaveAs($outputPath)

# Close documents
$document.Close([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges)
$mergedDocument.Close([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges)

# Quit Word application
$word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)


That module has been a bit of a thorn in my side. I've tried using it before with no success. I tried the code here and it threw the same errors that I got before. I was wondering if you have any idea as to what could be causing said errors. I'll add them to my question above

@Avarsiral I believe the problem with this script is this well-known thing :https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/you-receive-the-opening-this-will-run-the-following-sql-command-message-when-you-open-a-word-mail-merge-main-document-that-is-linked-to-a-data-source-aebb9d4b-003c-0d4b-2762-42ecdccbaced . To circumvent it, you need to have the correct data source connection details (or to be able to find them in the .docx, for example) and call OpenDataSource to reconnect.
